# Fazer Conversão Dos Nomes De Arquivos Para Letras Alfabeto

Tags: linux, while, terminal, for, shell-script

Fazer Conversão Dos Nomes De Arquivos Para Letras Alfabeto

**Por Exemplo**, tenho várias arquivos de imagens/fotos em um diretóro, e desejo passar esses nomes extensos das respectivas images em nomes designado por letras do alfabeto

## Antes

`IMG01-03082016.jpg`

`IMG02-03082016.jpg`

`IMG03-03082016.jpg`

etc ...

## Depois

`A.jpg`

`B.jpg`

`C.jpg`

etc ...

Comment: E se a quantidade de arquivos for maior que a quantidade de letras do alfabeto? Como vc ia nomear os arquivos que estão fora da faixa de letras do alfabeto?

Comment: `ls *.jpg /| head -26 | perl -nlE 'system ("echo mv $_ ". chr(64+$.).".jpg")' ` e apaga o "echo" se te parecer bem...

Comment: @Dener Carvalho Na verdade, não pretendo deixar dentro do diretório mais que 26 imagens que em números corresponde ao alfabeto. Ok!

Comment: @DiegoHenrique, como referido no comentário, se estiver a "mostrar" a operação pretendida, retira o "echo"  ficando `ls *.jpg /| head -26 | perl -nlE 'system ("mv $_ ". chr(64+$.).".jpg")'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue solução testado para o problema:

```
#/bin/bash

n=0

alfabeto=$(echo {A..Z})

find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.jpg' -type f  | while read imagem; do

    mv "${imagem}" "${alfabeto[n++]}.jpg"

done

exit 0

#fim-de-arquivo#
```

Answer (score 1):

O comentário de **JJoao** e a reposta de **Lacobus** me fez chegar ao *shell-script*:

```
 #!/bin/sh
 #
 # Por - Diego Henrique
 #
 # Programa - Renomear Arquivos Para Letras Do Alfabeto
 #
 # NOTA - Deve-se ter no máximo 26 Arquivos, alojado neste diretório 
 # Isso se dá ao número no qual corresponde as 26 Letras Alfabéticas 
 #
 n=0; LETRA=(A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z);

 ls $HOME/*.png | while read IMG; do mv "$IMG" "${LETRA[n++]}.png"; 

 done
```

> Isto foi o que funcionou perfeitamente no meu Sistema Pinguin - **Damn Small Linux**

Sobre minha própria experiência(erros/acertos), resolvi deixar isso como resposta absoluta.